# gitignore: Ignoring a folder (anywhere) except for a subfolder (anywhere)

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to exclude everything in a folder named `foo`, except for stuff inside a folder named `bar`.

`foo` can appear anywhere in the directory structure more than once.

`bar` can appear anywhere in the directory structure under `foo`.

I tried

```
/**/foo/**
!/**/foo/**/bar/**
```

but it didn't work. It still ignores all the `foo`. It refuses to allow `bar`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you try providing it in reverser oder? First !/**/foo/**/bar/**, then /**/foo/** ? I dont know if that will work, but I'd try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [gitignore documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> [A line starting with] An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. **It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**

It seems like this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

When you ignore a directory, you tell git to not even look there.

```
**/foo/**
```

ignores everything in `foo/`, including all the directories.  git will never even see a `bar` directory nested farther down because the above told it to not examine anything in `foo`

```
**/foo/**
!**/foo/**/
!**/foo/**/bar/**
```

will do it, because you overrode the ~don't look~ instruction with ~but do look in all the directories~.

When this alternative makes sense to you, [you understand everything](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html#_pattern_format):

```
**/foo/**
!**/foo/**/bar/**
!*/
```